# How do I search for a substring with a variable within a string and replace it with content that contains the substring variable with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, variables, preg-replace

Lets suppose I have a string:

```
$text = "This is my string exec001 and this is the rest of the string exec222 and here is even more execSOMEWORD a very long string!"
```

I want to replace each occurrence of "exec?" in the string with some new text and at the same time I want to store the text that follows "exec" in a separate variable so it can be used when replacing the text.

For example, say I want to replace each occurrence of exec??? with, 
    < html>???< /html>< div>???< /div>
, so that the resulting string is:

```
$text2 = "This is my string <html>001</html><div>001</div> and this is the rest of the string <html>222</html><div>222</div> and here is even more <html>SOMEWORD</html><div>SOMEWORD</div> a very long string!"
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: One of your question tags already names a possible solution. Look into [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) then.

Comment: Why do we need to store a variable when we only want to replace "exec".Rest of the string will anyways be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go using [preg_replace](http://php.net//manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$text = "This is my string exec001 and this is the rest of the string exec222 and here is even more execSOMEWORD a very long string!";
$text2 = preg_replace('/\bexec(\S+)/', "<html>$1</html><div>$1</div>", $text);
echo $text2,"\n";
```

This will replace all occurrences of `execwhatever`. 
`\S+`  stands for any NON space character.
`\b`  is a word boundary.

You may find more info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

**Output:**

```
This is my string <html>001</html><div>001</div> and this is the rest of the string <html>222</html><div>222</div> and here is even more <html>SOMEWORD</html><div>SOMEWORD</div> a very long string!
```

**Update according to comment**

If you want to replace more than one string, just do:

```
$text2 = preg_replace('/\bexec([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)/', "<html>$1</html><div>$2</div>", $text);
```

Where `[^:\s]` means any character that is not semi-colon or space

Comment: Thank you so much. This is fantastic. I'm very grateful for this solution!

Comment: Hi M42. I have one further question: How can I store multiple variables? For example: I want to replace execVARIABLE1:VARIABLE2:VARIABLE3 and store each of VARIABLE1, 2 and 3 in say $1, $2 and $3 when the string is rewritten. Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much M42!! That is exactly what I am after. You are - quite simply - a genius. One last revision: Is it possible to let one of the variables have spaces? For example execTest:This is a test:Hello. Here $1=Test, $2=This is a test and $3=Hello? Thanks once again in advance. Without you, I doubt I would have cracked this.

Comment: @user3931836: variables may have spaces only if there is a specific delimiter between them  (i.e. semicolon) even after the last variable. In this case, just remove `\s` from the character class.

Comment: Thanks again! Project complete my end thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
     exec\S+
```

This regex works replacing all exec words.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qK1pK7/1